# JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 5 of the JSON data

Tags: php, json, ajax, phpmailer

I have installed `phpmailer 6.8.1` (upgraded from `phpmailer 5.2`) into my server (using `php v7.0.33`).  The phpmailer is working as I am receiving the test emails however once the email data is processed/sent the `ajax` call returns to the calling page where I show the user a message that email was sent and it is this part which I am looking to correct.  The website's `contact.php` page sends the form data to `process_form.php` via `ajax` call:

```
    form.submit.addEventListener('click', function(){
        let first_name = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
        let telephone = document.getElementById('telephone').value;
        let email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        let textarea1 = document.getElementById('textarea1').value;
        let submit = document.getElementById('btn-submit').value;
        let messages = document.getElementById('form-messages').value;

        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        //debugger;
        /* WHEN FUNCTION COMES BACK FROM AJAX CALL WE RUN THIS FUNCTION */
        request.onload = function() {
            console.log('line 318 ', request.responseText);//
            let responseObject = null;
            /* CONVERTING JSON STRING INTO A STANDARD JS OBJECT */
            try{
                responseObject = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                //console.log(responseObject);

            } catch (e) {

                console.error('Could not parse JSON! (line ~327 in js code)', e.message);

            }
            /* IF THERE WAS NO ERROR - PASS INTO FUNTION */
            if (responseObject) {
                handleResponse(responseObject);
            }
        }; //END: request.onload = function() {
        const requestData = 'first_name='+first_name+'&telephone='+telephone+'&email='+email+'&textarea1='+textarea1;
        console.log('requestData = ' + requestData);

        /* MAKING A POST REQUEST HERE */
        request.open('post', '../scripts/process_form.php');
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        /* SENDING REQUEST BELOW */
        request.send(requestData);
    }); //END:
```

This is the error message in the page console:

```
e: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 5 of JSON data
```

The `json_encode` from `process_form.php` sends after processing the form data.  At this point in the code it is after the email was sent (all form fields validated) or no email was sent as error recorded in form field(s) and it specifies which form field(s) had incorrect data (thus the array):

```
    echo json_encode(
        array(
            'ok' => $ok,
            'messages' => $messages
        )
    );
```

`$ok` is boolean indicating correct user input or not
`$messages` indicates a string "successfully sent email" or specifies the error fields from what was passed via the form.

I receive nothing from `process_form.php` and when debugging on `contact.php`:

```
console.log('responseObject = ', responseObject);
```

`responseObject` is `null`

### UPDATE:  I was not reading the console log file correctly, apologies for confusion, but now that I can view my log messages within my code this is what I am seeing:

for:

```
       request.onload = function() {
            console.log('line 318 (responseText = ) ', request.responseText);//
```

I know I am sending correctly:

```
        const requestData = 'first_name='+first_name+'&telephone='+telephone+'&email='+email+'&textarea1='+textarea1;
        console.log('line 344 (requestData = ) ' + requestData);

        /* MAKING A POST REQUEST HERE */
        request.open('post', '../scripts/process_form.php');
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        /* SENDING REQUEST BELOW */
        request.send(requestData);
```

From console log: `line 344 (requestData = ) first_name=Brian D Rauch&telephone=6092843554&email=bxr0354@njit.edu&textarea1=Email Test 9/27/2023 (28)`

And `responseText` is perhaps messing - way too much information and no idea where it derives:

```
line 318 (responseText = )  2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: EHLO allcountyguitar.com<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: STARTTLS<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: EHLO allcountyguitar.com<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: AUTH LOGIN<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: [credentials hidden]<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: [credentials hidden]<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: MAIL FROM:&lt;kiteandwindsurfer@gmail.com&gt;<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: RCPT TO:&lt;allcountyguitar@gmail.com&gt;<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: RCPT TO:&lt;kiteandwindsurfer@gmail.com&gt;<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: RCPT TO:&lt;bxr0354@njit.edu&gt;<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: DATA<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: Date: Wed, 27 Sep 2023 19:08:23 +0000<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: To: allcountyguitar@gmail.com<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: From: &quot;AllCountyGuitar (via KiteandWindsurfer)&quot; &lt;kiteandwindsurfer@gmail.com&gt;<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: Cc: kiteandwindsurfer@gmail.com<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: Reply-To: Information &lt;bxr0354@njit.edu&gt;<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: Subject: Inquiry from AllCountyGuitar Website!<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: Message-ID: &lt;ZFfDRcpjYvDQf0bwoMdYSmWhrJgpx23UTmCYCNLaZc@allcountyguitar.com&gt;<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.8.1 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: <br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: <br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:             &lt;div style=&#039;color:#33691e;background-color:#f1f8e9; font-family: Tahoma; padding:20px; width:60%; border:solid 1px #dcedc8;&#039;&gt;<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:             &lt;h1&gt;Email Inquiry From AllCountyGuitar.com:&lt;/h1&gt;<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:             &lt;p&gt;Date: Wed, Sep 27, 2023&lt;/p&gt;<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:             &lt;p&gt;Name: Brian D Rauch&lt;/p&gt;<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:             &lt;p&gt;Telephone: 6092843554&lt;/p&gt;<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:             &lt;p&gt;Email Address: bxr0354@njit.edu&lt;/p&gt;<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:             &lt;br&gt;<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:             &lt;div&gt;Comment:&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;Email Test 9/27/2023 (27)&lt;/div&gt;<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:             &lt;h3&gt;END OF MESSAGE&lt;/h3&gt;<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:             &lt;/div&gt;<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:         <br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: <br>
2023-09-27 19:08:23 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: .<br>
2023-09-27 19:08:24 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: QUIT<br>
{"ok":true,"messages":["Thank you, your message has been sent!"]}
```

and lastly the `responseObject` never gets beyond `null`
`responseObject = JSON.parse(request.responseText);`

Comment: `console.log('line 318 ', request.responseText);` What does this print?

Comment: Thanks for replying @tkausl - here is the console output: `Could not parse JSON! (line ~327 in js code) JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 5 of the JSON data contact.php:944:25
    onload https://allcountyguitar.com/contact/contact.php:944
    (Async: EventHandlerNonNull)
    <anonymous> https://allcountyguitar.com/contact/contact.php:930
    (Async: EventListener.handleEvent)
    <anonymous> https://allcountyguitar.com/contact/contact.php:919`

Comment: Watch the request in your Network tab and see what the response is.

Comment: @kiteandwindsurfer: That's the output from the `console.error` statement in the `catch` block.  But you're also outputting a `console.log` statement *before* the `try` block, which should show the actual data you're trying to parse.  What is that data?

Comment: ok, thanks @David, the line `console.log('line 318 ', request.responseText);` I do not see in the console tab - odd but it does not appear present either in the debug tab.  For what it is worth, the last entry on either tab is `Request to access cookie or storage on “https://c.clarity.ms/c.gif?ctsa=mr&CtsSyncId=63B11FD4CFB14E0AB28E69F7F32481AD&MUID=0E015424C16E63E43C8B45DEC00C62CC” was blocked because it came from a tracker and content blocking is enabled` prior to the error of `could not parse JSON...`

Comment: @kiteandwindsurfer: Any way you look at it, if `JSON.parse` is failing to parse the data then your immediate debugging step is to *observe* that data.  Either by outputting it to the console, or using a breakpoint in the script debugger, or observing the response in the network tab.

Comment: It's 2023. Use `fetch()` instead of `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: I have updated my main post to reflect log console files which were missing.  Thanks again to @tkausl and others for pointing this out.

Comment: @kiteandwindsurfer: `request.responseText` is definitely *not* JSON.  It looks like your server-side code is outputting a lot more than the code shown is indicating.  You'll want to further examine your server-side code to find out where it's doing that.  As it stands, with the information shown in the question, `JSON.parse` is doing exactly what it is expected to do... throwing an error when it's given non-JSON data.

Comment: thanks @David, that seems a correct re-framing of the problem.  This extra text came from upgrading to new version of phpmailer - it is odd to me how all that gets included in the responseText.  At this point when the email is sent (`$ok` is `true`) all I need is a message "...email sent" along with the `$ok`, can I not just work around the odd responseText to accomplish?

Comment: @kiteandwindsurfer: Well, if you don't want to change what the server returns then you'd need to manually parse that returned data.  It's not in any standard format, so you'd be looking at various string manipulation operations and/or perhaps a regular expression.  I recommend instead that you fix the server-side code to not output this additional information that you don't want to use in the client-side code.  It would be cleaner, easier to work with, use less network data, and not expose potentially sensitive information.

Comment: yes @David, good suggestion.  And regarding fixing the server side code, it is probably a parameter of `$mail` in phpmailer which is returning extra...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenting out the `$mail->SMTPDebug` declaration solved the issue.

```
// $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
```

Arriving at this would not have been possible without the **VERY** helpful comments by @David, @aynber and @tkausl.

The upgrading of PhpMailer was stressful as I am not any technophobe thus very tentative.  Early on, I set the debug parameter and didn't pay it any mind until tracing the problem to its roots.